# WebApi not accepting RestSharp AddJsonBody

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a WebApi endpoint I can call with curl ok :

```
curl -X POST "https://endpoint/SendPin?email=john@smith.com" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

WebAPI looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendPin")]
    public async Task<bool> SendPin([Required] [EmailAddress] string email)
    {
        ....
    }
```

**Problem:** The server returns a BadRequest message "Email is required" when I call it with RestSharp???

```
    var request = new RestRequest("SendCode");
    request.AddJsonBody(new { Email = "john@smith.com"});
    RestClient client = new RestClient(TheUrl);
    var response = await client .ExecutePostTaskAsync<bool>(request );
```

It appears RestSharp is not sending to the url as a param??

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the email to the request body with the `request.AddJsonBody()` method.
Instead, add it to the request url as a querystring like you have done in the curl request

```
var request = new RestRequest("SendPin"+ "?email=john@smith.com");
RestClient client = new RestClient(TheUrl);
var response = await client.ExecutePostTaskAsync<bool>(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the parameter is a simple type, I need to call it like his:

```
request.AddParameter("email", credential.Email, ParameterType.QueryString);
```